# Error on Samsung S4: "UNFORTUNATELLY the process . com.google.process.gapps has stopped."

Tags: crashes, google-apps

I am getting an error message on my new S4. It is  "UNFORTUNATELLY the process . com.google.process.gapps has stopped."

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: A little context might help. Did you just start your phone when that happened? Or did you just install some new app? Was that error there from the beginning? What did you do immediately before it appeared, what were you trying to do when it happened?

Answer (score 1):

2 Things to try:

1. Go to Settings->Apps->All->Find 'Download Manager' and open it. Make sure it's enabled.
2. Go to Settings->Apps->All->Find Google Play Store and open it. Clear the data and the cache.

Try again.